# What are Java Packages, .NET Assemblies and .NET Namespaces and is a Java package the same as a .NET Namespace?

Tags: java, .net, programming-languages

So my question is: **What are Java Packages, .NET Assemblies and .NET Namespaces and is a Java package the same as a .NET Namespace?**

I have used Google to get the following:

**Java Package:** 
Java Packages provide a way of organizing files into different directories according to their functionality, usability and as well as category that they should belong to. An example of a package is the JDK package.

**.NET Assembly:**
A .NET assembly provides a fundamental unit to physical code grouping.

**.NET Namespace:**
A .NET namespace provides a fundamental unit of logical code grouping.

I have read about them, but haven't really understood, can anyone please explain further?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between assembly and namespace is, as you've pointed out, that the former organizes code *physically*, and the latter *logically*. Assemblies are your DLL and EXE files. Namespaces are just the dot notation that'll help you find your classes as you write code.

A Java package is very similar to a .NET namespace. In Java, each public non-nested class needs to have its own *.java-file, and the packages must have their corresponding directories, so that's why you'll read references to directories when reading up on java packages, but not in .NET, as a single file can contain several .NET namespaces, and a single namespace can be scattered across several directories.